# Hide DIVS when clicking a button that pass a paremeter from a php variable

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to develop a javascript function to hide/show specific divs when a certain button is clicked. The number of DIVS is variable depending on the page, so sometimes there will be one div, other times there will be three and so on, which is why I am trying to pass a php variable as part of the parameter. Let me put the PHP code:

```
$cent = 0;
$selectors = "";
$divs = "";
if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
            $selectors .= "<button class='selection-buttons' onClick = showHide(things" . $cent . ")>" . $cent . "</button>";
            $divs .= "<div id='things" . $cent . "' class='hideable'>THINGS</div>";
            $cent = $cent + 1;
        }
}
return $selectors . $divs;
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function showHide(id){
  var divid = document.getElementById(id);
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hideable");
  for (var div in divs) {
     div.style.display = "none";
  }
  divid.style.display = "block";
 }
```

The problem here is that, when clicking on the button, nothing happens. Am I parsing something wrong? When reading the html sourcecode the onClick function is correct (showHide(things1), showHide(things2),...).

Probably the mistake is so stupid I am gonna facepalm like crazy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you would need quotes inside the braces when calling the function with a parameter `showHide(things` ~ quotes around `thingsX` etc. Check the console for errors

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Weirdly enough, without the quotes the code works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to modify your PHP code to get some array's rolling:

```
<?
    
$cent = 0;
$selectors = "";
$divs = "";


// Since you do not provide anything to actually start the loop, lets make a random for loop:
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $selectors .= '<button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things' . $cent . ')">' . $cent . '</button>';
        $divs .= '<div id="things' . $cent . '" class="hideable">THINGS</div>';
        $cent = $cent + 1;
} 

echo $selectors . $divs;

?>
```

So using a static output of your PHP array thingy, the output of the javascript code can be viewed below. It is basically working version of whatever you were trying to do. If its supposed to work like that, I dont know..

```js
function showHide (divid) {
    const divs = document.getElementsByClassName('hideable');
    
    for (let div of divs) {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    divid.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things0)">0</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things1)">1</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things2)">2</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things3)">3</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things4)">4</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things5)">5</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things6)">6</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things7)">7</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things8)">8</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things9)">9</button><button class="selection-buttons" onClick="showHide(things10)">10</button><div id="things0" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things1" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things2" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things3" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things4" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things5" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things6" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things7" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things8" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things9" class="hideable">THINGS</div><div id="things10" class="hideable">THINGS</div>
```

Your problem seemed to be, that the `divid` coming into `showHide()` was already an element, so there is no need for:

```
var divid = document.getElementById(id);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Such a tiny thing...BTW, I saw a lot of people putting commas within the function. Is that really necessary? Haven't had problems without them.

Comment: You mean quotes?  Yes they are important and requires, but surprisingly not a problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the quotes. You code generate `showHide(things0)` where things0 will be interpreted as variable, while you want it to be a string `showHide('things0')`.

Fixed php will looks like this:

```php
$cent = 0;
$selectors = "";
$divs = "";
if ($data->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $data->fetch_assoc()) {
            $selectors .= "<button class='selection-buttons' onClick='showHide(\"things" . $cent . "\")'>" . $cent . "</button>";
            $divs .= "<div id='things" . $cent . "' class='hideable'>THINGS</div>";
            $cent = $cent + 1;
        }
}
return $selectors . $divs;
```